# Global Variables within wordpress action when including the file.

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with variable scope. I am trying to include global variable from function_processor.php to function_function.php within my theme.

Contents of form_processor.php

```
$variable = ['value1', 'value2'];
```

Contents of form_functions.php

```
include('form_processor.php');
global $variable;
print_r($variable);
```

if I use function.php and just do a standard include('form_function.php'); everything works but if I try to do the same via wordpress action it fails to retrieve global variable.

Example when it fails

```
function contact_form_deps()
{
    require_once('form_functions.php');
}

add_action('init', 'contact_form_deps');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand when the variable will be accessible.  By putting the require_once into the method and having the method triggered by the event, the variable will not be in scope during the initial loading of the file.

Move the require_once out of the method and place it before the first use within the .php file.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.